# Create Horizontal Custom Layout CollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've been trying to figure out how to implement this specific type of custom layout for my CollectionView for a while now.

[image]

I basically want a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that scrolls horizontally from right to left (but I would like to be able to switch the orientation on demand from right to left or left to right).

I also always want a button at the end of the section either at the bottom left or the bottom right depending on if I can scroll from right to left or left to right.

What's the best way to implement a custom layout like this? Is there an example explaining how to use `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`? I've been very lost on this for a while now.

More specifically:

1. How can I configure a `UICollectionView` and it's adjacent `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to scroll horizontally from left to right or right to left?
2. How can I always have a button on the bottom left or bottom right depending on if if the layout scroll from right to left or left to right?
3. Can someone explain how `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` work with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? There is a lot of complicated documentation on this but no really good examples for my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this problem by using the following steps by just setting the `.forceSemanticAttribute` to `.forceRightToLeft`

It should set the initial position for the collectionview at the rightmost position.

Although expanding animations have issues here, it solved my problem!